# Calling function inside closure, Swift

Tags: swift, function, closures

```
private func showOrder() {
        disableButtons()
        var count = 0

        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { time in

            self.popColor(color: self.colorOrder[count])
            count += 1

            if count == self.colorOrder.count {
                time.invalidate()
                self.depopAllButtons()
                self.enableButtons()
            }
        }
    }
```

In this function I am looping through an Array of colors. The popColor() method is used to add shadows and such to a button the screen.

The issue that I am having is that the popColor() function seems to execute after the closure has executed, so it is always one behind where it should be. The error this causes is on the last iteration of the loop the last color doesn't execute its popColor().

Is it possible to call a function inside of a closure as I am doing here with popColor()?

Comment: It should be fine to do that. Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the closure and stepping through to see what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have write your code with small changes:

```
var count = 0
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { time in
    debugPrint("set color")
    count += 1
    if count == 3 {
        time.invalidate()
        debugPrint("disable set color")
    }
}
```

And the console printed:

```
"set color"
"set color"
"set color"
"disable set color"
```

Your timer is working correctly. Look for a problem elsewhere.